# Unhandled exception at (memory address) (msvcr110.dll)

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm having a problem with this code. It's a genetic algorithm I'm writing for the traveling salesman problem. However the program just crashes and doesn't complete, digging around in the debugger I found what I believe the error is however I'm not sure where it is occurring. I'll just post the whole program since I have been pouring over the code and I can't pinpoint the error. Thanks.

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<time.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>

const int numcities = 15;
using namespace std;

class City{
public:
    int x,y,numcity;

    City();
    ~City();
    void setxcoord(int);
    void setycoord(int);
    int getxcoord();
    int getycoord();
    void setcitynum(int);
    int getcitynum();
};

City::City(){
    x = -1;
    y = -1;
}

City::~City(){
}

void City::setxcoord(int xcoord){
    x = xcoord;
}

void City::setycoord(int ycoord){
    y = ycoord;
}

int City::getxcoord(){
    return x;
}

int City::getycoord(){
    return y;
}

void City::setcitynum(int newcitynum){
    numcity = newcitynum;
}

int City::getcitynum(){
    return numcity;
}

class resultscontainer{
public:
    vector<City> tour;
    int i;
    vector<City>::iterator it;

    resultscontainer();
    ~resultscontainer();
    City findcity(int);
    void addcity(City);
    int toursize();

};

resultscontainer::resultscontainer(){
i = 0;
}

resultscontainer::~resultscontainer(){};

void resultscontainer::addcity(City newcity){
    it = tour.begin() + i;
    tour.insert(it,newcity);
    i++;
}

City resultscontainer::findcity(int index){
    City temp = tour.at(index);
    return temp;
}

int resultscontainer::toursize(){
    return tour.capacity();
}

class newtour{
public:
    vector<City> candidate;
    vector<City>::iterator it;
    double fitness,distance;
    string citylist;

    newtour();
    ~newtour();
    void makeindividual(resultscontainer);
    double getfitness();
    double getdistance();
    bool fulltour();
    void displaytour();
    void setuniquepos(int, City);
    City getcityatpos(int);
    bool isEmpty(int);
};

newtour::newtour(){

    City initvalue;
    for(int i =0; i < numcities ; i++){
        it = candidate.begin() + i;
        candidate.insert(it, initvalue); 
    }
}

newtour::~newtour(){};

void newtour::makeindividual(resultscontainer citylist){
    for (int i = 0; i < numcities; i++){
        it = candidate.begin() + i;
        candidate.insert(it, citylist.findcity(i));  
    }
    random_shuffle(candidate.begin(), candidate.end());
}

double newtour::getfitness(){
    fitness = 1/getdistance();
    return fitness;
}

double newtour::getdistance(){
    for(int i = 0; i+1 < candidate.capacity(); i++){
        City currentcity = candidate.at(i);
        City destinationcity = candidate.at(i+1);
        distance += sqrt(pow(currentcity.x - destinationcity.x, 2) + pow(currentcity.y - destinationcity.y, 2));
    }
    return distance;
}

bool newtour::fulltour(){
    if(candidate.capacity() == numcities) return true;
    else return false;
}

void newtour::displaytour(){
    citylist = "Tour is: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < candidate.capacity(); i++)citylist += candidate.at(i).getcitynum() + ", ";
}

void newtour::setuniquepos(int i, City newcity){
    it = candidate.begin()+i;
    candidate.insert(it, newcity);
}

City newtour::getcityatpos(int i){
    return candidate.at(i);
}

bool newtour::isEmpty(int i){
    if(candidate.at(i).getcitynum() == NULL) return true;
    else return false;
}

class population{
public:
vector< newtour > totalpop;
int index,maxpop;
vector< newtour >::iterator it;

population();
~population();
void addtour(newtour);
newtour findtour(int);
newtour findfittest();
int populationsize();
};

population::population(){
    index = 0;
    maxpop = 10;
}

population::~population(){}

void population::addtour(newtour candidate){
    it = totalpop.begin() + index;
    totalpop.insert(it, candidate);
    index++;
}

newtour population::findtour(int i){
    return totalpop.at(i);
}

newtour population::findfittest(){
    newtour fittesttour;
    for(int i = 0; i+1 < totalpop.capacity(); i++){
        newtour currenttour = totalpop.at(i);
        newtour nexttour = totalpop.at(i+1);
        if(currenttour.getfitness() <= nexttour.getfitness()) fittesttour = nexttour;
    }
    return fittesttour;
}

int population::populationsize(){
    return totalpop.capacity();
}
```

Above is the header file, below is the implementation.

```
#include"City.h"
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<time.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

const double mutationrate = .1;
const int bracketsize = 5;

newtour bracketselection(population pop){
    population temppop;
    for(int i = 0; i < bracketsize; i++){
        int randomnum = (int) (rand() * pop.populationsize());
        temppop.addtour(pop.findtour(randomnum));
    }
    newtour best = temppop.findfittest();
    return best;
}

newtour crossover(newtour mom, newtour dad){
    newtour child;
    bool inside = false;
    int beginning, end;
    beginning = (int) (rand() * mom.distance);
    end = (int) (rand() * mom.distance);

    for(int i = 0; i < numcities; i++){
        if(beginning < end && i < end && i >beginning)child.setuniquepos(i, mom.getcityatpos(i));
        else if (beginning > end){
            if (!(i>end && i < beginning)){
                child.setuniquepos(i, mom.getcityatpos(i));
            }
    }
}
    for(int j = 0; j < numcities; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k <numcities; k++)if(child.getcityatpos(k).getcitynum() == dad.getcityatpos(j).getcitynum())inside = true;
        if(!inside)for(int l = 0; l < numcities; l++)if(child.getcityatpos(l).getcitynum() == NULL){
            child.setuniquepos(l,dad.getcityatpos(l));
            break;
        }
    }
    return child;
}

void mutation(newtour subject){
for(int i=0; i < numcities; i++){
    if(rand()* 5 / rand() < mutationrate){
        int j = (int)(bracketsize *8 %5 * rand());
        City randcity1 = subject.getcityatpos(i);
        City randcity2 = subject.getcityatpos(j);
        subject.setuniquepos(j, randcity1);
        subject.setuniquepos(i, randcity2);
        }
    }
}

population evolve(population totalpop){
    population nextgen;
    nextgen.addtour(totalpop.findfittest());
    for(int i = 1; i < nextgen.maxpop; i++){
        newtour mom,dad,child;
        mom = bracketselection(totalpop);
        dad = bracketselection(totalpop);
        child = crossover(mom,dad);
        nextgen.addtour(child);
    }
    for (int i =1; i < nextgen.maxpop; i++)mutation(nextgen.findtour(i));
    return nextgen;
}


void main(){
    City city1,city2,city3,city4,city5,city6,city7,city8,city9,city10,city11,city12,city13,city14,city15;
    population thepop;
    resultscontainer cities;

    city1.setxcoord(5);
    city1.setycoord(2);
    city1.setcitynum(1);
    city2.setxcoord(16);
    city2.setycoord(3);
    city2.setcitynum(2);
    city3.setxcoord(13);
    city3.setycoord(5);
    city3.setcitynum(3);
    city4.setxcoord(15);
    city4.setycoord(9);
    city4.setcitynum(4);
    city5.setxcoord(10);
    city5.setycoord(10);
    city5.setcitynum(5);
    city6.setxcoord(4);
    city6.setycoord(9);
    city6.setcitynum(6);
    city7.setxcoord(6);
    city7.setycoord(12);
    city7.setcitynum(7);
    city8.setxcoord(12);
    city8.setycoord(13);
    city8.setcitynum(8);
    city9.setxcoord(9);
    city9.setycoord(14);
    city9.setcitynum(9);
    city10.setxcoord(16);
    city10.setycoord(20);
    city10.setcitynum(10);
    city11.setxcoord(18);
    city11.setycoord(18);
    city11.setcitynum(11);
    city12.setxcoord(2);
    city12.setycoord(5);
    city12.setcitynum(12);
    city13.setxcoord(7);
    city13.setycoord(5);
    city13.setcitynum(13);
    city14.setxcoord(2);
    city14.setycoord(16);
    city14.setcitynum(14);
    city15.setxcoord(11);
    city15.setycoord(18);
    city15.setcitynum(15);

    cities.addcity(city1);
    cities.addcity(city2);
    cities.addcity(city3);
    cities.addcity(city4);
    cities.addcity(city5);
    cities.addcity(city6);
    cities.addcity(city7);
    cities.addcity(city8);
    cities.addcity(city9);
    cities.addcity(city10);
    cities.addcity(city11);
    cities.addcity(city12);
    cities.addcity(city13);
    cities.addcity(city14);
    cities.addcity(city15);

    thepop = evolve(thepop);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++){
        thepop = evolve(thepop);
    }

    newtour bestroute = thepop.findfittest();

    cout << "The fittest route had a fitness of: " <<bestroute.fitness<< endl;
    cout << "The algorithm determined that the best route is :" << endl;
    bestroute.displaytour();
    cout << "With a total distance of: " << bestroute.getdistance();
}
```

Comment: Somewhere you're going out of range. I get this error: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'`

Comment: Posting your entire program here and saying "I have a vaguely described problem. Please find it for me." isn't quite how SO works, and "I found what I believe the error is however I'm not sure where it is occurring" but I won't tell you what I found isn't a problem description. The "memory address" you've glossed over gives information, and you can use `cout` statements to help locate at least the area causing the problem. Once you've done that, you can ask a specific question about that area of the code and perhaps we can help. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for suggestions.

Comment: You've got at least a couple of loops that iterate up to `<container>.capacity()` (I see two of these for `candidate.capacity()`, for example).  The capacity gives you the number of elements the container has space for, but not the number of elements actually in the container, which can be less.  If you call `candidate.at(3)` for a container that has a capacity of 8 but a size of 2, for example, it'll throw an `std::out_of_range` exception, which is what you're getting.  You should be using `capacity.size()` instead, which gives you the actual number of items in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be using `size()` to get the number of elements in your containers, not `capacity()`.  This is true for the loops, as I mentioned in the comment above, but also for `population::populationsize()`.
2. You call [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) and multiply it by the population size.  I think you're expecting `rand()` to return a floating point value from 0 to 1, but it actually returns an integer from 0 to RAND_MAX (which is at least 32767).  Rather than multiply it by the population size, you should modulus it by the population size:

   ```
   int randomnum = rand() % pop.populationsize();
   ```
3. Modulus by zero will crash your program, just like division by zero, so you need to test that `pop.populationsize()` is non-zero before generating the random number in #2 above.
4. In `newtour::displaytour()`, you attempt to concatenate a string with the integer `candidate.at(i).getcitynum()`.  This won't work; you'll need to convert the integer to a string first.  I'd suggest using [`ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str)
5. `main()` must return an `int`.  MSVC might be letting you use `void main()`, but it's not standard-compliant and GCC refuses to take it.

With these fixes, your program gives the following output:

> The fittest route had a fitness of: 5.50124e+306
>   The algorithm determined that the best route is :
>   With a total distance of: 1.81777e-307

It doesn't quite look right to me, but at least it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using rand() incorectly.
For example:

```
int randomnum = (int) (rand() * pop.populationsize());
temppop.addtour(pop.findtour(randomnum));
```

randomnum will be complete nonsense and most likely accessing out of bounds in pop.
I think you want something like `(int)(rand() % pop.populationsize())`

Also learn debugging in VS( just see your call stack, step your code and see variable values )
also use push_back instead of insert in your add...() functions.

Answer (score 0):

A large part of your problem appears to be a misunderstanding - or simply lack of understanding - of how vectors work. You also seem to have a penchant for the dangerous practice of storing vector iterators as class members instead of using local variables.

Lets take a quick tour of how you use vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Address
{
    int          m_doorNo;
    std::string  m_street;

    Address() : m_doorNo(-1), m_street("Limbo")
    {
        std::cout << "Address() default ctor called\n";
    }

    Address(int doorNo, const std::string& street)
        : m_doorNo(doorNo), m_street(street)
    {}
};

// So we can << an Address object.
static std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Address& address)
{
    os << address.m_doorNo << " " << address.m_street.c_str();
    return os;
}

// Give our *usage* of a vector a friendly name.
typedef std::vector<Address> AddressBook;

int main()
{
    AddressBook book;
    if (book.empty())
        std::cout << "book starts empty, it has size() of " << book.size() << '\n';

    book.push_back(Address(70, "1st Street"));
    std::cout << "First address added, book.size = " << book.size() << '\n';

    book.push_back(Address(123, "Hope Avenue"));
    std::cout << "Second address added, book.size = " << book.size() << '\n';

    std::cout << "address[0] is: " << book[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << "address.at(1) is: " << book.at(1) << '\n';

    std::cout << "*address.begin() is: " << *(book.begin()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "address.front() is: " << book.front() << '\n';
    std::cout << "address.back() is: " << book.back() << '\n';

    // couple more addresses.
    book.insert(book.begin(), Address(3, "Disco Alley"));
    book.insert(book.begin() + 1, Address(5, "Mortimer Lane"));

    // overshoot, place an extra address at the end of the vector.
    book.insert(book.end(), Address(999, "Hellfire Drive"));
    // oops, lets erase that.
    book.pop_back();

    std::cout << "Done shuffling. Size = " << book.size() << " while capacity = " << book.capacity() << '\n';

    const size_t numAddrs = book.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numAddrs; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": " << book[i] << '\n';
    }

    // and lastly, lets use a reverse iterator.
    std::cout << "backwards:" << '\n';
    // instead of std::vector<Address>::iterator etc, we can say AddressBook::iterator
    for (AddressBook::reverse_iterator it = book.rbegin(); it != book.rend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }

    // 'reserve' adjusts the capacity, it tells the vector to go ahead and
    // allocate space for N entries, but don't make them available yet.
    book.reserve(999);

    // 'resize' changes the size, if the new size is smaller than the capacity,
    // it forces a call to reserve to allocate more memory.
    // after that, it goes ahead and grows the array storage by default-
    // initializing any new entries.
    book.resize(9);

    std::cout << "book.size = " << book.size() << " but cap = " << book.capacity() << '\n';

    // at this point, it is safe to say:
    book[6].m_doorNo = 555;
    book[7].m_street = "Nowhere";
    book[8] = Address(10101, "Binary Bend");

    for (auto it = book.begin(); it != book.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```